# Get ID of front-page for each sub-site has mixed results

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to get a list of all the homepage id's for all the sites on a WordPress multisite install. I'm using this code below to do that..

```
$subsites = get_sites();

foreach ( $subsites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );

    $site_data = [
        'id' => get_current_blog_id(),
        'home_id' => get_option( 'page_on_front' )
    ];

    restore_current_blog();
    $sites[] = $site_data;
}
```

But I'm getting some weird results using `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`. Some id's are returning as strings, others as integers, and a couple of them as false. Each site has a static front page assigned and the "Page on Front" option under the individual site settings do have values filled out. Any ideas on why I'm getting mixed results when trying to get the homepage id? Or is there another way to find the id other than the `get_option( 'page_on_front' )` option?

**$sites dump**

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(4) "1862"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(4) "2542"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(3) "905"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["home_id"]=>
    int(1384)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(4) "2885"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["home_id"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(8)
    ["home_id"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["home_id"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
    ["home_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there different themes on these sites? Maybe some themes change this setting.

Comment: @Nikolay they all have the same theme set on them.

Comment: Weird. Well it is only strings on my multisite. Even the ones without, have a string "0". I guess try going to one of those that are not string and save the Reading settings again. Also some plugin could be filtering and changing those values. You can go in the database to see what are the values there, or deactivate all plugins.